# Find all functions $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that: $f\left(x^3\right)+f\left(y^3\right) = (x + y)f\left(x^2\right)+f\left(y^2\right)-f(xy)$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

Here is the question:

> Find all functions $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that:
> $$f\left(x^3\right)+f\left(y^3\right) = (x + y)f\left(x^2\right)+f\left(y^2\right)-f(xy)$$

**What I tried:**

Note that the function $f\left(x^3\right)+f\left(y^3\right)$ is symmetric. From here we get
$$(x + y)f\left(x^2\right) + f\left(y^2\right) - f(xy) = f(x + y)f\left(y^2\right) + f\left(x^2\right) - f(xy)$$
which gives $(x + y - 1)f\left(y^2\right) = (x + y - 1)f\left(x^2\right)$.
From here I cannot proceed further. I could have cancelled $(x + y - 1)$ but I haven't proved that $(x + y - 1) \neq 0$ and neither I don't know how to proceed with $\left(y^2\right) = f\left(x^2\right)$ even if we can cancel $x + y - 1$. Any hints or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The equation looks mighty like something is missing from it. A couple of brackets, maybe? $f(x^3) + f(y^3) = (x + y)\color{red}{\Big(}f(x^2) + f(y^2) - f(xy)\color{red}{\Big)}$

Comment: No sorry , that bracket is actually not there in the question .

Comment: A pity. I wish it were there.

Comment: No problem @IvanNeretin

Comment: Are you sure? @Maths-Lover This question is meaningless i there are no red brackets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to get $f(x^2) = f(y^2)$.

If $x+y-1 \neq 0$, we must have $f(x^2) = f(y^2)$. F any $x^2$ and $y^2$, pick a $z$ such that $x+z-1$ and $y+z-1$ are nonzero, which is always possible by taking $z \neq 1-x, 1-y$. Then $f(x^2) = f(z^2) = f(y^2)$. So $f(x^2) = f(y^2)$ for all reals $x, y$, and hence $f$ is constant on nonnegative reals.

Comment: oh yeah thanks I got it , so $f(x^2) = f(y^2)$ for all reals $x,y$ which means $f$ is constant on non-negative reals , are there any other solutions?

Comment: To deal with negative reals, set both $x$ and $y$ to be negative. Then $x^2, y^2, xy$ are all positive, so we get $f(x^3)+f(y^3) = a(x+y)$, where $a$ is the constant value that $f$ takes on the positive reals. From here, vary $y$ while fixing $x$ to get $f(y^3) = ay$, and then substitute the solutions back into the original equation to see which work.